# Limit Zooming Geometry Features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, geometry, visualisation

I draw flag feature on my map as follows:

```
myVectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Flag Geometry", {
renderers: renderer,
isBaseLayer: true,
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
        fillColor: "red",
        strokeColor: "gray",
        label: "${label}",
        fontColor: "${favColor}",
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        labelYOffset: 2 //for flag
    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"])),
        "select": new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"]))
})
});

var pointList = [];
var xs = [0, 0, 240, 240, 8, 8, 0];
var ys = [0, 280, 280, 120, 120, 0, 0];

for(var p=0; p<6; ++p) {
    var newPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(camera.get('latitude') + xs[p],
        camera.get('longitude') + ys[p]);

    pointList.push(newPoint);
}
pointList.push(pointList[0]);
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointList);
var flagVector = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]));

flagVector.attributes= {
    label: 'label',
    favColor: 'blue', //favorite color
    align: "cm"
};
myVectorLayer.addFeatures([flagVector]);
```

This zooms by default when zooming the map but when zooming out the feature becomes so small that it disappears. Is there a way to limit this zooming effect for the feature so that it stops zooming out the feature after a certain level?

Answer (score 1):

You can control this with for example

```
minScale: 54168.1
```

On the layer, or use style rule and use :

```
    maxScaleDenominator: 60000000,
    minScaleDenominator: 433344,
```

The values are of course not hardcoded.  That will let you control the layout depending on any zoomlevel.

I've written a [more detailed code sample here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31635) , hope this helps.

**edit:**
Can't seem to get this to get drawn in jsfiddle, feel free to fork/edit and let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/gplv2/9YBYG/

Comment: Unfortunately none of these ways affect the geometry drawn in this above mentioned way.

Comment: What way are you expecting it to behave ?  Not so sure If I truly get the issue now.

Comment: Using Renederer.Symbol as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496810/openlayers-graphic-feature-with-own-symbol minScale works perfectly, but then I face this geometry center problem.

Comment: Trying your code, I get this: *ReferenceError: camera is not defined* so I suspect it's defined before the copy/paste.  Any chance to fill out the blanks, I got a jsfiddle -almost- working

Comment: camera.get('latitude') & camera.get('longitude') can be replaced by any valid latitude/longitude values e.g. 3658281.05255/4855543.17503

Comment: I think I'm understanding your problem better, I assume you tried attributes xOffset / yOffset already ?  It's in the example you took the code from?

Comment: yes but no effect too

Comment: I tried finding the same solution to this problem, but then on the labels in the styles, I didn't find a way to offset those.  I'm still playing with this atm

Comment: for the graphics label this 'labelYOffset/labelXOffset' worked well

Comment: This could be in fact a bug imho, since the docs do seem to propose xOffset/yOffset would do the job.  what version of openlayers are you using ?

Comment: OpenLayers 2.11

Comment: It looks like `Method: drawLinearRing` is in the deprecated list. see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/deprecated.js , looks like including this file would be a worthy effort...